# Linq to Entity Framework: Multiple left outer joins create full outer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, join

I can't find a good example, probably I'm searching wrong:

I have a bunch of tables joined via expression syntax and I'd like to left outer join two more, if there are values, otherwise return NULL.

So the sql is looking like this:

```
select              *
from                table1 mr
left outer join     table2 on table1
left outer join     table3 on table2
left outer join     table4 on table3
where               mr.id = 1234
```

So a left join is no problem with the syntax like this:

```
join oiA in query1 on organisation.Id equals oiA.Organisationid into qOrgInhA
from oiA in qOrgInhA.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

But as soon as I add the other tables depending on the oiA, the Entity Framework produces a Cross-Join, and not a second left outer join.

From what I've read, GroupJoin might be the solution, but I really can't find a good example, the most examples I found have just 2 tables.

Or am I doing something totally wrong?

Comment: Can you show the LINQ query that isn't working?

Comment: The linq is very huge and the problem is just a small example, basically the question is how to create multiple left outers without telling the EF to create a cross join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method syntax, multiple left joins can be done like this:

```
var result = table1
.GroupJoin(table2, o => o.Key, i => i.FKey, (t1, t2) => new 
{ 
    t1, 
    t2.GroupJoin(table3, o => o.Key, i => i.FKey, (_t2, t3) => new 
    {
        _t2,
        t3
    })
});
```

The resulting query produced by entity framework will be similar to:

```
select * from table1
left outer join table2 on table1.Key = table2.FKey
left outer join table3 on table2.Key = table3.FKey
```

**Edit:**
I'm a bit shaky on query syntax, but its the same idea of doing the second join within the select:

```
 var result = from t1 in table1
 join t2 in table2 on t1.Key equals t2.FKey into joinresult
 select new
 {
     t1,
     from jr in joinresult
     join t3 in table3 on jr.Key eq t3.FKey into joinresult2
     select new
     {
         jr,
         joinresult2
     }
 }
```

Comment: Is there a possibility to do the same with expression syntax? Since the linq is huge and I can't rewrite everything

Comment: I updated the original answer. Someone may need to correct me on the syntax as I rarely use that form.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. According to your Syntax it seems like I dont Need any DefaultIfEmpty at all

Comment: Does not seem to work with this syntax, but I see your idea probably I can google it out